# Execute Stored procedure in .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is my code. For `FromSqlInterpolated`, it can run without error but the stored procedure is not run imo. For `ExecuteSqlCommand`, when it runs, it has syntax error at `@p0`

```
        var a = "abc";
        var b = 10;
        var result = _dataContext.FileFolders.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXECUTE dbo.AddFileFolderStructure {10} {a} {a}");

       // _dataContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.AddFileFolderStructure @p0 @p1 @p2", b, a, a);

        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

I have also tried below

```
        var id = new SqlParameter("id", 10);
        var folderName = new SqlParameter("folderName", "1");
        var folderType = new SqlParameter("folderType", "5");
        var result = _dataContext.FileFolders.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.AddFileFolderStructure {id} {folderName} {folderType}");

        _dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You have to wrap value into SqlParameter object before passing

Comment: Tried but still the same. No error but stored procedure is not executed.

Comment: @Steve I believe Vimal's comment aimed `.ExecuteSqlCommand` use (`a` and `b` should be `SqlParameter` there)

Comment: How did you confirm that the procedure is not executed. Use sql profiler to verify it. also execute directly in database to see if any result exists

Comment: @VimalCK the query is clearly wrong, there's no need to verify anything. The SQL statement uses angle brackets instead of proper parameter names

Comment: @Steve if you [check the doc examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) you'll see that parameter names must start with `@`. Your query uses angle brackets just like the `FromSqlInterpolated` query though. `FromSqlRaw` expects a *valid* SQL query.  If a query runs in SSMS it should be able to run with `FromSqlRaw`. What you posted wouldn't run

Comment: @Steve the doc examples show how to pass parameters by position or name too. If you use `EXECUTE dbo.AddFileFolderStructure @id @folderName @folderType` you'll pass the parameters by position

Comment: do i need _dataContext.SaveChanges()?

Comment: I have tried to run it directly at database and it works. `EXECUTE dbo.AddFileFolderStructure 10, '1', '22'`

Comment: @VimalCK okay i will use sql profiler to verify it.